# Immediately calling a number after creating a conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions, twilio-node

I am handling outgoing calls using Twilio Functions. I am creating a conference every outgoing call but I want to immediately call the number after creating the conference.

```
if(event.To) {
  const dial = twiml.dial()
  dial.conference('My Room', {
      endConferenceOnExit: false,
      startConferenceOnEnter: false
  });
} else {
  twiml.say('Thanks for calling!');
}
```

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
if(event.To) {
  const dial = twiml.dial()
  dial.conference('My Room', {
      endConferenceOnExit: false,
      startConferenceOnEnter: false
  });
  dial.number(event.To);
} else {
  twiml.say('Thanks for calling!');
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from you explanation what you are trying to do. Can you explain the use case? From above, you are making an initial outbound call using a Twilio Function. Then when the person answers, you want to add them into a conference and then make another outbound call and add another party to the same conference?

Comment: I edited the code. The use case is I want to establish a call after the outbound call is answered, not when a conference is created.

Answer (score 0):

A few different ways to do this. If you are using a URL with the Calls Resource (to initiate the outbound call), if the URL is accessed, the call was answered. You can then returned [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do next.

Alternatively, can use the `statusCallback` of the [Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource), to see if the call was answered. If it was answered, you can then execute additional code to take the next steps.